# How to Handel and Push the Data into drill down column charts in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Below string which I created from backing bean , then I created the JavaScript file for drill down chart and I passed the values string into that created method for drill down chart. My problem is where ,if i hard code this below data into series : [...etc] its working good,but i need to use the string which comes from backing bean

```
{
name: ' Chart ', 
colorByPoint: true,
data: [{name: ' Indeals ', y: 1150,drilldown: ' Indeals ' },
       {name: ' NR ' ,y: 1050,drilldown: ' NR ' },
       {name: ' Die ' ,y: 950,drilldown: ' Die ' },
       {name: ' CL ' ,y: 900,drilldown: ' CL ' },
       {name: ' Win ' ,y: 1100,drilldown: ' Win ' }]
},
drilldown .. ....
```

I have attached sample code here: http://jsfiddle.net/7jevddL4/71/

**javascript**

```js
$(function () {

    var brandsData = [],
        drilldownSeries = [];

    brandsData = [{
        name: "Drive",
        y: 1,
        drilldown: "drive"
    },];
    drilldownSeries = [ {
        "data": [
            ["Tiger Team", 10]
        ],
        id: "drive"
    },];
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Team",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: brandsData
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: drilldownSeries
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How you communicate your backend with data? By AJAX? Are you able to paste your code here?

Comment: its a string which comes from java class to javascript , i need to know how to push the datas into series as well with respective drilldown

Comment: You should use the native JSON, not a string, because type is different.